# Stm32f4discovery - OpenOCD - telnet uploading demo program

Tags: stm32, openocd, stm32f4discovery

I have problem trying to upload demo program into fresh stm32f4discovery board, this is what i'm doing:

1. Connect board to computer
2. openocd -f board/stm32f4discovery.cfg
3. telnet localhost 4444

   ```
   Open On-Chip Debugger
   > reset init
   target state: halted
   target halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
   xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0xfffffffe msp: 0xfffffffc
   > flash write_image demo.hex       
   device id = 0x10016413
   flash size = 8192kbytes
   flash write algorithm aborted by target
   error executing stm32x flash write algorithm
   flash memory write protected
   flash write failed = 00000010
   error writing to flash at address 0x08000000 at offset 0x00000000
   in procedure 'flash'
   ```

   What am I doing wrong ? I've tried flash protect, stm32f2x unlock but response is still the same: 'flash memory write protected', i've missed something ? I'm using pre-compiled demo program from st.com from package 'STM32F4-Discovery_FW_V1.1.0' from 'Project/Demonstration/Binary'.

Comment: Which version of OpenOCD do you use? Which JTAG interface do you use, a ST Link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flash memory must be deleted before you rewrite it.

```
monitor flash protect 0 0 11 off
monitor flash erase_address 0x08000000 0x40000
monitor flash write_image erase *"/path/to/hex/file.hex"* 0 ihex
```

Or instead of telnet and hex files, use arm-none-eabi-gdb and ELF with the following commands:

```
arm-none-eabi-gdb
target remote localhost:3333
monitor reset halt
file */path/to/elf/file.elf*
load
monitor reset
continue
```

Note that when using ELF files, you do not need to specify the address where it will be (usually 0x08000000 or 0x08008000 with bootloaders).

Also, consider using a bootloader like [OpenBLT](http://www.feaser.com/openblt/doku.php), it will help you to master the principles like VTOR, offsets, stack addresses etc.